# Problema con manage.py al usar runserver y class Meta

Tags: python, django-models

Hola espero me puedan ayudar, estoy creando un formulario basado en modelo pero me al momento de correr el servidor me aparece el siguiente error

```
(entorno1) C:\proyectosDjango\refugio>manage.py runserver Watching for file changes with StatReloader Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py ", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py ", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ambientes\entorno1\lib\site-packages\django\utils\ autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ambientes\entorno1\lib\site-packages\django\core\m anagement\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ambientes\entorno1\lib\site-packages\django\core\m anagement\base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ambientes\entorno1\lib\site-packages\django\core\m anagement\base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ambientes\entorno1\lib\site-packages\django\core\c hecks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ambientes\entorno1\lib\site-packages\django\core\c hecks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ambientes\entorno1\lib\site-packages\django\core\c hecks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ambientes\entorno1\lib\site-packages\django\urls\r esolvers.py", line 398, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ambientes\entorno1\lib\site-packages\django\utils\ functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ambientes\entorno1\lib\site-packages\django\urls\r esolvers.py", line 579, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ambientes\entorno1\lib\site-packages\django\utils\ functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ambientes\entorno1\lib\site-packages\django\urls\r esolvers.py", line 572, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__ init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in
_call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\proyectosDjango\refugio\refugio\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('mascota/',include(('apps.mascota.urls','mascota'))), # apps.mascota.ur ls es la direccion donde se encuentra el archivo, 'mascota' es el identificador   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ambientes\entorno1\lib\site-packages\django\urls\c onf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__ init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in
_call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\proyectosDjango\refugio\apps\mascota\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from apps.mascota.views import Home, mascota_view   File "C:\proyectosDjango\refugio\apps\mascota\views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from apps.mascota.forms import mascotaForm   File "C:\proyectosDjango\refugio\apps\mascota\forms.py", line 4, in <module>
    class mascotaForm(forms.ModelForm):   File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ambientes\entorno1\lib\site-packages\django\forms\ models.py", line 266, in __new__
    raise FieldError(message) django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (edad_aproximada, vacuna) sp ecified for Mascota
```

el error solo ocurre cuando la clase meta la pongo con 'M' mayuscula y la 'M' debe de ser asi

Aca el codigo del formulario

```
from django import forms
from apps.mascota.models import Mascota

class mascotaForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta: #aca es el error 

        model =Mascota

        fields = [
            'nombre',
            'sexo',
            'edad_aproximada',
            'fecha_rescate',
            'persona',
            'vacuna',
 ]

        labels = {
            'nombre': 'Nombre',
            'sexo': 'Sexo',
            'edad_aproximada': 'Edad aproximada',
            'fecha_rescate':'Fecha rescate',
            'persona':'Adoptante',
            'vacuna':'Vacuna',

 }

        widgets = {
            'nombre': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'sexo':  forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'edad_aproximada':  forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'fecha_rescate': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'persona': forms.Select(),
            'vacuna': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        }
```

Comment: Puedes agregar tu modelo, parece ser que algunos campos como edad_aproximada y fecha_rescate no se encuentran en el modelo

Answer (score 0):

Segun la ultima linea del error log, la aplicacion no encuentra los campos edad_aproximada  y vacuna, revisa la clase Mascota.

`FieldError: Unknown field(s) (edad_aproximada, vacuna) sp ecified for Mascota`

Estaria bueno que pongas la version de Django que estas utilizando, ya que en la documentacion de la version 2.2 los labels se setean de la siguiente manera:

`labels = {'name': _('Writer'),}`

En versiones anteriores se seteaban de la siguiente manera:

`#change the label in forms
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClientForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].label = "Nombre"
        self.fields['surname'].label = "Apellido"`